# Can I add roads to my mapBox map, for my Flutter app use?

Tags: flutter, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I want to use the Navigation SDK of Mapbox on rivers in my Flutter app. So I was wondering if I can add roads on top of the water layer. If not, is there a way to use the Navigation SDK with polylines? Or does anyone have another idea ?

I'm not asking for code, but if that's possible with Mapbox (or any kind of map).

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add roads to show a route. There is [mapbox_navigation](https://pub.dev/packages/mapbox_navigation) package. It supports only Android.

Also, there is [google_maps_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter) package. You can draw polylines using it.

Comment: I can't try the mapbox's navigation package since the MapBoxMapView crashes as soon as I run the app. But it looks like a good solution, I'll close this topic and reopen a new one for my error. Thanks !

Comment: Ok, then you can upvote the answer :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/64539212/10659482